# Raspberry Pi and CMOS camera

Tags: pi-3, camera

I am newbie in RPI, so I am sorry for my silly question :).

I want to buy https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/ and connect it with camera from this intercom: https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/2016-3-5-inch-LCD-Touch-Screen-120-Degree-Digital-Doorbell-Peephole-Viewer-Door-Eye-Doorbell/32646777018.html?scm=1007.13338.58753.0&pvid=9dfdb584-86c5-4f52-9882-d225e072f381&tpp=1&detailNewVersion=&categoryId=15380314

This intercoms CMOS camera has such connector:
[image]

Is it possible to connect this camera to RPI 3 Model B with connector like https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Raspberry-Pi-Camera-Module-China-Version-Free-Shipping-Dropshipping/32378644924.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2,searchweb201603_1&btsid=67830895-4907-44a2-ad14-e163b0fc3f98 ?

Thank you!

Comment: **That's not a connector.**  That's *a camera* (presumably a knock-off of the official one).

Comment: Yeah, that's camera. But I planned to remove "original" camera from that module and connect camera of this intercom, instead of "original" camera.

Comment: You can't remove the camera from that module.  All you can do is disconnect the ribbon cable, and that will not do you any good (if it would, you can buy them separately for a few dollars).

Comment: Pity. Where can I buy cheap peaphole, that could be connected to RPI? )))

Comment: The lens mount on that will fit inside an 8 mm hole.  The lens itself is much smaller, ~1 mm.  Take a close look at the photograph.

Comment: Aaaaaand? ))) Smaller, but what about ready-to-use cameras in package like this? https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1vdpeKVXXXXbaXFXXq6xXFXXXv/206067809/HTB1vdpeKVXXXXbaXFXXq6xXFXXXv.jpg?size=37026&height=800&width=800&hash=ee453313b9aed032a0ef8efe7487f225

Comment: That does not look smaller to me.  I would guess the outer circumference is almost as big as the PCB from the other module.  Anyway, unless you find something that is sold explicitly for the CMI connector on the Raspberry Pi you are stuck with USB.

Answer (score 1):

No, unless the camera is a clone of one of the Raspberry Pi current (two is it?) cameras.

The cameras themselves are pretty dumb devices.  All the hard work of image processing is done on the Pi (by the GPU) to deliver photos and video.  That hard work is tailored to a specific camera model.